# Cómo superponer un texto a un svg en html

Tags: html, css, div, svg

Estoy practicando HTML+CSS y tengo la siguiente duda:

*¿Cómo superponer un texto a un svg haciendo uso de css pero sin depender de un position absolute hacia el top de la página?*

O sea, es muy fácil hacer esto:

```
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 4%;
z-index: 2;
```

Pero yo no quiero que dependa del top de la pantalla... Quiero que esté encima de el top usando algo como `margin-top: -0.7em;` o sea lo que pretendo es que se superponga el texto y la imagen pero no dependiendo del top de la página.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>LoQueSeaMi</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="author" content="FelipedelosH" />
      <!-- Incluir Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- Incluir Bootstrap JS y dependencias de Popper.js -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    <style>
    .tarjeta svg{
      color: grey;
      width: 40%;
      height: 40%;
    }
    
    .kip_total{
      color: red;
      margin-top: -0.7em;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="tarjeta">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M12.5 16a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7Zm1.679-4.493-1.335 2.226a.75.75 0 0 1-1.174.144l-.774-.773a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l.547.548 1.17-1.951a.5.5 0 1 1 .858.514ZM11 5a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0ZM8 7a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4Z"/>
                <path d="M8.256 14a4.474 4.474 0 0 1-.229-1.004H3c.001-.246.154-.986.832-1.664C4.484 10.68 5.711 10 8 10c.26 0 .507.009.74.025.226-.341.496-.65.804-.918C9.077 9.038 8.564 9 8 9c-5 0-6 3-6 4s1 1 1 1h5.256Z"/>
              </svg>
              <p class="h1 kip_total">400</p>
              <p class="h3 kip_description">Usuarios felices</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adjunto mockups de qué es lo que deseo:

[image: original]

[image: deseado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para centrar el contenido podés asignarle al contenedor **col** `display: flex` y hacerlo relativo, de esta manera, los hijos podrán estar en posiciones absolutas pero en base a su padre.

Luego, al SVG podés colocarlo absoluto y moverlo hacia el medio del contenedor en el eje y utilizando los atributos de **top** y **transform**:

```
.tarjeta svg {
  color: grey;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 150px; 
  height: auto; 
}

.kip_total{
  color: red;
}

.container_kip{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
.col {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```
<body>
  <div class="tarjeta">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M12.5 16a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7Zm1.679-4.493-1.335 2.226a.75.75 0 0 1-1.174.144l-.774-.773a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l.547.548 1.17-1.951a.5.5 0 1 1 .858.514ZM11 5a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0ZM8 7a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4Z"/>
            <path d="M8.256 14a4.474 4.474 0 0 1-.229-1.004H3c.001-.246.154-.986.832-1.664C4.484 10.68 5.711 10 8 10c.26 0 .507.009.74.025.226-.341.496-.65.804-.918C9.077 9.038 8.564 9 8 9c-5 0-6 3-6 4s1 1 1 1h5.256Z"/>
          </svg>
          <div class="container_kip">
            <p class="h1 kip_total">400</p>
            <p class="h3 kip_description">Usuarios felices</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era lo que estaba buscando :)